# Solve mechanical drawing, defined by geometrical constrains in a symbolic way

Tags: gratis, geometry, symbolic-algebra

I have a mechanical 2D drawing that is specified by certain geometrical constrains and would like to solve it for certain variables (like angles and distances). The end result would be a closed-form expression.

E.g. for a rectangular triangle with opposite side *a* and adjacent side *b*, the closed form for the hypotenuse equation would be *c=sqrt(a^2+b^2).*

I'm looking for a *free* tool that could automate this (I suspect [Geometry Expressions](http://www.geometryexpressions.com/) is a commercial tool that can do this). I also would suspect, that [solvespace](http://solvespace.com/) could do this, since it [uses a symbolic algebra system](http://solvespace.com/tech.pl), but I couldn't access any equations.

It would be nice to have a gui (but not necessary). A generic symbolic equation system solver on its own would be too uncomfortable. I would prefer if such a tool would run under Windows or Linux.

Comment: Does the OS matter? Does it need a GUI, or would a command-line tool suffice? Any preferences on "how to enter data", and "what format the output should be"?